# Percona PMM's clickhouse doesn't clean up old metric_log directory

Tags: pmm

We've got Percona's PMM installed for a few years now in docker with the `/srv` directory mounted to the filesystem.

We've spotted that the clickhouse service isn't cleaning up its data in the directory `/srv/clickhouse/data/system/metric_log`. Some of the directories there are over 2 years old and some still contain +150MB data. I think we can clean this up, but I couldn't find any documentation about this on pmm websites.

I could manually remove these directories, but I expect pmm (or clickhouse) has some retention mechanism available for it.

I've also verified that pmm's retention works as expected since I don't have any data available in the pmm dashboard older than the retention period configured in pmm.

A short list of the size (and names) of those directories:

```
--- /srv/clickhouse/data/system/metric_log -----
  130.5 MiB [##########] /202312_8404047_8653546_1838
  105.5 MiB [########  ] /202207_2445036_2694502_2246
   99.6 MiB [#######   ] /202301_4676883_4912218_2210
   95.6 MiB [#######   ] /202307_6644116_6874350_2392
   94.1 MiB [#######   ] /202305_5942426_6168500_2386
   92.4 MiB [#######   ] /202112_5912_265478_2749
   92.3 MiB [#######   ] /202212_4205342_4421596_2234
...
```

Most of the data is stored in `[dir]/event_time_microseconds.bin`.

As you can see, some of these directories are old but still contain quite some data.

Answer (score 0):

From the config examples mentioned in their documentation, these files are most probably kept there because they have not reached the thresholds (read more here https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#metric_log).

I would not take the risk of removing them manually since I can't predict the result. Rather, you could try to temporarily disable the `metrics_log` and, once the directories are cleanup up and space is reclaimed, you can reenable the logs.

That would certainly require you to stop PMM's clickhouse server, modify the config, then start the server.

In other words, if you run it in a docker container, here are three steps

1. stop the server: `docker exec -it pmm-server supervisorctl stop clickhouse`
2. change clickhouse configuration via an override:

```
To disable metric_log setting, you should create the following file
"/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/disable_metric_log.xml" with the following content:

<clickhouse>
<metric_log remove="1" />
</clickhouse>
```

3. start the server: `docker exec -it pmm-server supervisorctl start clickhouse`

Please make sure you have a full backup of PMM's `/srv` directory before proceeding with any changes so you can recover if things go wrong :)